# Error with syntax for BayesGLM in R with Gaussian family

Tags: r, bayes

I am trying to fit a Bayes glm model with an inverse Gaussian family and `link="identity"`. However, I'm getting the following messsage:

```
Error in if (iter > 1 & abs(state$dev - devold)/(0.1 + abs(state$dev)) <  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

My code is as follows:

```
age<-bayesglm(formula=y~factor(x1)+factor(x2)+factor(x3)+factor(x4)+fact‌​‌​or(x5),
  family="inverse.gaussian"(link="identity"),prior.scale=Inf,prior.df=Inf,‌​da‌​ta=data)
```

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Could you please show what your code looks like?  It will help us understand why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

Its telling you that the condition evaluates to `NA`. One of the variables in the condition is missing - `iter`, `devold` or `state$dev`. My guess is its probably `state$dev` but we can't *possibly* tell from the limited information you have given so far.

If you look at the code for `BayesGLM` you will probably be able to see what `iter`, `devold` and `state$dev` were set to, and then see how `state$dev` relates to arguments in the call you made to `BayesGLM`, which is possibly where the problem lies.

Comment: My code is as follows:age<-bayesglm(formula=y~factor(x1)+factor(x2)+factor(x3)+factor(x4)+factor(x5),family="inverse.gaussian"(link="identity"),prior.scale=Inf,prior.df=Inf,data=data)

Comment: Can you put all relevant information into your question, please, rather than just in comments? You'll also find it easier to format. Then to get my attention, comment to mention it.

Comment: My code is as follows:age<-bayesglm(formula=y~factor(x1)+factor(x2)+factor(x3)+factor(x4)+fact‌​or(x5),family="inverse.gaussian"(link="identity"),prior.scale=Inf,prior.df=Inf,da‌​ta=data)

Comment: I included the code as part of my question. The same code works if i replace "identity" with "inverse"

Comment: That, too, sounds like highly relevant information. Please add that last sentence to the information in your question. Could you also delete the comments with code please? They're not needed now.